# Abort the driver immediately when any of the executor fails

Tags: apache-spark, kill, abort, executor, accumulator

while loading data into database if particular column is a bad record
If one executor fails then driver needs to be updated with the message and job has to be terminated

I thought to do using accumulator.Please give me suggestion of how to do this.....
Attached my code below...

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark= SparkSession.builder().appName("loadSqlData").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

        Properties connectionProperties= new Properties();
        connectionProperties.put("user","postgres");
        connectionProperties.put("password","root");

        Dataset<Row> personcsvdata = spark.read().option("header","true").csv("C:\\Users\\Manasa\\Documents\\nulldata.csv");
        personcsvdata.show();

        LongAccumulator countErrors = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator();

        try {
            personcsvdata.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "public.employee", connectionProperties);

            countErrors.add(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
}
```

Comment: It's one of the very basic principles of Spark that a job should _not_ fail if an executor task fails. Probably a better approach would be to run a check over that data before trying to write the data into the DB.